# Docker CMD executable 'not found' - LUA

Tags: build, lua, docker

I have successfully built an image and if I go in through bash, I am able to execute "lua" from the command line.

Here is part of the build:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install lua5.1 lua-socket lua-sec

CMD [“lua”]
```

When I run the docker image, the error I keep getting is:

> /bin/sh: 1: [“lua”]: not found

When I build it with:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/lua"]
```

I then get this when I run it:

> /bin/sh: 1: [“/usr/bin/lua”]: not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are including the brackets and quotes when you shouldn't be... given that error message.

Comment: Are you accidentally using "smart" quotes?